# Create array from huge string by parts

Tags: java, android, arrays, string, split

I have this huge string

```
String vStr = "('1','uno'),('2','dos'),('3','tres'),('4','cuatro')...('1000000','one millon')"
```

when i use the

```
vStr.split('),(')
```

i have an error **outOfMemory exception in string.split**

How can I do a split ? but to 500 parts at the time ?

Comment: Most likely, there is a better overall solution for whatever it is that you are trying to accomplish here. What exactly are you planning on doing with the pieces of this string (whether all of them at once or 500 at a time)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd like to limit the number of resulting parts, just add desired parts as second argument of split() method.

```
vStr.split('),(', 500)
```

And maybe do this however many times you need in a loop or something.

Comment: Thanks perfect answer, by the way, I finished using the StringUtils from apache commons-lang3, the method StringUtils.splitByWholeSeparator, this method works fast, and not thrown the outofmemoryexception